# Write unit test for reducer but - TypeError: state.commentList is not iterable

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, jestjs, enzyme

**this is the commnetsReducer.js file**

```
import { ADD_COMMENT } from "./actionType";
// let initialState = {
//   commentList : []
// };

const commnetsReducer = (state = { commentList: [] }, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ADD_COMMENT:
      return { ...state, commentList: [...state.commentList, action.payload] };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default commnetsReducer;
```

**this is the unit test for above reducer commnetsReducer.test.js **

```
import commnetsReducer from "../reducer";
import { ADD_COMMENT } from "../actionType";
// const uuid = require("uuid");

describe("comment reducer ", () => {
  it("should returns initial state", () => {
    expect(commnetsReducer(undefined, {})).toEqual({
      commentList: []
    });
  });

  it("handle action of type SAVE_COMMENT ", () => {
    expect(
      commnetsReducer([], { type: ADD_COMMENT, payload: "new comment" })
    ).toEqual({commentList :['new comment']});
  });
});
```

**this is the error I got in console **

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f8f46.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
commnetsReducer([], { type: ADD_COMMENT, payload: "new comment" })
```

You've passed in an array as the state. Arrays have no `.commentList` property, so when your reducer tries to spread `state.commentList` you get that error from trying to spread undefined.

Instead, pass in a state with the right shape, such as:

```
commnetsReducer({
  commentList: []
}, { 
  type: ADD_COMMENT, 
  payload: "new comment" 
});
```